# How to display data from firestore using react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display data from firestore on the home page but i dont seem to get it working. I want to show all the data in the collection. the collection includes name, id, location etc...

```
    import Firebase from "./lib/firebase";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SnapshotViewIOS } from "react-native";
// export async function getRestaurants(restaurantsRetrieved) {
//   var restaurantList = [];

//   var snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection("Restaurants").get();

//   snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
//     restaurantList.push(doc.data());
//   });

//   restauantsRetrieved(restaurantList);
// }
export default () => {
  const [restaurantsList, setRestaurantsList] = useState([]); //Initialise restaurant list with setter
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const getRestaurants = async () => {
    try {
      const list = [];
      var snapshot = await Firebase.firestore().collection("Restaurants").get();
      console.log("Here");
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push(doc.data());
      });
      setRestaurantsList(list);
    } catch (e) {
      setErrorMessage(
        "There's nae bleeding restaurants, I told you to upload them!"
      );
    }
  };

  //Call when component is rendered
  useEffect(() => {
    getRestaurants();
  }, []);

  return (

  <View style={tailwind('py-10 px-5')}>
    <Text style={tailwind('text-4xl font-bold')}>
      {restaurantsList}
    </Text>
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The State is not updating becuase it just taking the reference of list. So you need to update the like code below

```
.....

setRestaurantsList([...list]);

......
```

Comment: Hi @Ferin i get this error then "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {address, longitude, ID, image(url), name, price, phone,  latitude}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: {restaurantsList}  you cannot print data like this inside <View> tag.

Comment: Its working now just had to put the return into a FlatList ! thank you